# How do I use a .csv file to create a dictionary and use it as a function?

Tags: python-3.x, opencsv

I have a .csv file that I imported and basically what I need is to create a dictionary from the .csv file and use it along with my existing code. I want to be able to use it as a function and be able to call upon the new dictionary and its values when needed. Here is what I have so far:

#### csv file content:

> Price Volume 52WeekHigh 52WeekLow DividendYield PE_Ratio
>   150.75 41.03 233.47 142 1.97% 12.34
>   98.65 3.23 114.55 87.54 1.60% 23.03
>   340.53 4.74 394.28 292.47 2.51% 19.03
>   129.77 4.2 173.24 112.06 2.68% 20.15
>   111.77 5.67 133.88 100.22 4.04% 14.8
>   111.42 8.73 120.2 97.68 1.61% 13.05
>   175.37 2.69 275.31 151.7 1.83% 12.31
>   177.89 4.72 215.43 158.09 2.37% 18.85
>   119.83 4.76 171.13 105.94 5.35% 18.65
>   47.74 22.75 57.5995 42.04 2.54% 14.44

#### code snippet

```py
import csv
#import csv file.
    invest_dict = 'DOW_Stock_short.csv'


    with open(invest_dict , 'r') as invest_obj:
        invest_dict = 'DOW_Stock_short.csv'
        invest_reader = csv.reader(invest_obj)
        result = {}
        for row in invest_reader:
            if invest_reader.line_num !=1:
                key = row[0]
                result[key] = row[1]
        print(result)






    print("The purpose of this project is to provide Stock Analysis by reading \n the data from a csv file and performing analysis on this data.")
    def Greeting():
        print(".........Welcome.............")




    def Conversions(investment_amount):



          investment_amount = float(investment_amount)

          Euro = float(round(investment_amount / 1.113195,2) )

          Pound = float(round(investment_amount / 1.262304,2) )

          Rupee = float(round(investment_amount / 0.014316,2) )

          print("The amount you invest in euro is:  {:.2f}" .format(Euro) )
          print("The amount you invest in pounds is:  {:.2f}" .format(Pound) ) 
          print("The amount you invested in Rupees is:  {:.2f}" .format(Rupee) )




    def minimum_stock():
        key_min = min(result, key = (lambda k: result[k]))
        print("The lowest stock you can buy is: ",result[key_min])



    def maximum_stock():
        key_max = max(result, key = (lambda k: result[k]))
        print("The highest stock you may purchase is: ",result[key_max])



    def invest_range(investment_amount):
                new_list = []
                new_list = [i for i in result if i > 50 and i < 600]
                return(sorted(new_list))
    answer = 'yes'

    while answer:



    print(Greeting())

    try:
        investment_amount = float(input("Please enter the amount you want to invest:$ "))
        print("Thank you for investing:$ {:,.2f}".format(investment_amount))
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid amount...")
        continue 

    print(Conversions(investment_amount))






    for i in result:
        i = investment_amount
        if i <25:
            print("Not enough funds to purchase stock")
            break
        elif i>25 and i <250:
            print(minimum_stock())
            break
        elif i >= 250 and i <= 1000:
            print(maximum_stock())
            break

    print("This is the range of stocks you may purchase: ", invest_range(investment_amount))

    answer = input("Would you like to complete another conversion? yes/no " )
    if answer == 'no':
        print("Thank you for investing.")
        break
```

Comment: Please trim your sample code down to only the relevant portions. It would also be helpful if you could show us a sample of what the csv file looks like, and what you expect the resultant `dict` to look like.

Comment: Sorry, I was at work in a rush to post this. The .csv is as follows:

Comment: Price Volume 52WeekHigh 52WeekLow DividendYield PE_Ratio
150.75 41.03 233.47 142 1.97% 12.34
98.65 3.23 114.55 87.54 1.60% 23.03
340.53 4.74 394.28 292.47 2.51% 19.03
129.77 4.2 173.24 112.06 2.68% 20.15
111.77 5.67 133.88 100.22 4.04% 14.8
111.42 8.73 120.2 97.68 1.61% 13.05
175.37 2.69 275.31 151.7 1.83% 12.31
177.89 4.72 215.43 158.09 2.37% 18.85
119.83 4.76 171.13 105.94 5.35% 18.65
47.74 22.75 57.5995 42.04 2.54% 14.44

Comment: OK, great. And what are you expecting the resulting `dict` to look like?

Comment: Well based on my current code.,I want the header of the file to be stripped, and all I need is to get the symbol and price.

Comment: If I just run the imported dictionary from my code I get this: {'AAPL': '150.75', 'AXP': '98.65', 'BA': '340.53', 'CAT': '129.77', 'CVX': '111.77', 'DIS': '111.42', 'GS': '175.37', 'HD': '177.89', 'IBM': '119.83', 'INTC': '47.74', '': ''}.  Which is what I want, but now I need to know how to fit it into a function to call out and make the rest of my code comply with it.